# what is exact difference between <a><button>...</button></a> and <button><a>...</a></button>?

Tags: html

I have been using this interchangeably and the working is same. Is there really any difference? 
which method should be use in which cases?

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="http:\\www.google.com"><button> click </button></a>
        <button><a href="http:\\www.google.com"> click </a></button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't nest interactive elements!

Comment: @Oriol thanks for that specific statement. Now that i have read that part of documentation it is more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are forbidden in HTML. So use neither.

- If you want to link somewhere. Use `<a href=""></a>`.
- If you want to submit a form. Use `<button></button>`
- If you want a control to trigger JavaScript (and can't figure out how to do it with [progressive enhancement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement)), use `<button type="button"></button>`

Then apply CSS to make it look the way you want.

Comment: but sometimes i use it like " click on this button to go to back page " what to do in this case?

Comment: @SanketDeshpande — Ideally? Delete that entirely. Browsers have back buttons built in. People know how to use them. They work the same way on every website. (Failing that, then you aren't linking anywhere and you aren't submitting a form so you are stuck on option 3 and JavaScript that calls history.back).

Comment: understood, i used it for many other purposes like go to home page, subscribe channel etc. But now option 3rd it is.

Comment: "go to homepage" — that would be "if you want to link somewhere"

Comment: "subscribe channel" sounds like "if you want to submit a form"